# Syntax highlighting and styling using r-markdown for PowerPoint

Tags: r, r-markdown, powerpoint

I use R-Markdown to generate a PowerPoint presentation. The presentation contains code snippets. The R keywords are properly highlighted.

Is there a way to modify the style of the code blocks?

For example, having a grey background for the code snippets would help easily detect where the code is, in a presentation. Choosing the colors for the key words or displaying line numbers would also be great.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a *"syntax highlighting and styling code blocks"*, I advice you using **Slidy, Ioslides or Beamer** instead of Powerpoint.

You can apply some predefined CSS classes for backgrounds: *"bg-primary", "bg-success", "bg-info", "bg-warning", and "bg-danger"* and, certainly, your own rules.

**Example:**

```
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(
     name=c("A","B","C","D","E") ,  
     value=c(3,12,5,18,45)
)
     
ggplot(data, aes(x=name, y=value, color = "data")) + 
     geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

**How it will look:**

[image]